# Service undefined when function called async

Tags: angular, promise, async-await

In a component I have a simple method calling a service:

```
  sendRequest() {
    this.myService
      .doStuff()
      .then((res) => { ... }
  }
```

This `doStuff()` method is an `http.post` converted `toPromise()`

```
  doStuff(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.post(somewhere).toPromise();
  }
```

In this component I have another child component that receives a function as @Input() (it's a simple button)

```
<my-child [callback]="sendRequest"></my-child>
```

When I click on this button, I get a

> Cannot find property doStuff of undefined

If I call the following instead of doStuff, I get the expected behaviour:

```
  async testMe() {
    console.log("wait 5 sec");
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000));
    console.log("finished");
  }
```

I'm basically trying to implement this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypqkcf-eduhze?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.ts

With an http.post instead of a timeout promise.

Comment: seems like your service isn't in your component. what does your component constructor look like?

Comment: @ChrisNewman service is injected correctly. I can call it on click directly with (click)="sendRequest()" on a simple button. But not from the child component

Comment: try adding a console.log(this) at the start of sendRequest(). You'll probly see that 'this' is referring to your child component, which doesn't have the service in it's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the function as an Input. It then loses the context. The `this` in `sendRequest` no longer refers to the parent component. Possible workaround is to pass a lambda to the `Input`, like this:

```
const lambda = () => this.sendRequest()
```

And in html:

```
<my-child [callback]="lambda"></my-child>
```

By the way passing a callback as an `Input` to a child component is not a very good idea. Assuming the function you pass is to be called by the child component on a certain **event**, just emit that event with an `Output` from the child component and subscribe to it using Angular template syntax:

```
<my-child (onEvent)="sendRequest()"></my-child>
```